# Animal offerings as philanthropic gifts when the Holy Temple (Beit HaMikdash) returns?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban, third-temple

When the Beit HaMikdash returns, and animal offerings are reinstituted, will one be able to, in accordance w/ halakha, brand his sacrifice with his (or his family's) name on it, similar to the way families put their names on plaques that adorn synagogue walls, monuments, memorials, etc? Ditto other types of offerings?

Comment: Why would someone want to put their name on the animal? The animal doesn't stay in the temple forever

Comment: Middot 3:8 could be relevant?

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA, why would one want to put their name on a sacrifice which will be slaughtered not long after it was given? Putting names on plaques that adorn synagogue walls etc stay there for a very very long time.

Comment: offerers could take pictures of it, or the Beit Mikdash administration could sell official portraits of the branding or put them up on a wall? Maybe the part of the hide that was branded preserved?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Does branding constitute a מום?

Comment: like taking a selfie with the Kohen and the animal? I'm not sure if the logistics can work, because to bring into the Temple any sort of camera device would be violating the prohibiton of bringing in חולין לעזרה. I found that this would be a dispute between the Rambam and the Ran see here (https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52444&st=&pgnum=309), which would emerge that according to the Rambam no Kohen can enter the temple with any personal belongings...

Comment: @rosends what does מום (apparently pronounced "moom" mean? Defect/blemish? Isn't cattle branded, including kosher cattle?

Comment: @DragonOfDojima yes, a moom is a disqualifying blemish. I just don't know if branding would create a disqualification automatically. Kosher cattle is not held to the standard as ritually qualified to be a sacrifice.